# Unity device movement

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I'm trying to move a game object when i raise/lower (Shake) my phone but I don't know how get the device's movement. I already know about Input.acceleration but that just gives me the devices rotation and I want it's actual movement.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You can only measure changes in the acceleration of the phone with the accelerometer or changes in the rotation of the phone with the gyroscope, but that is pretty much it. You can use math to calculate other value like it's absolute rotation by combining the data of the accelerometer and gyroscope in a process called sensor fusion, but that still won't get you the whatever you mean with movement of the phone.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the Input.acceleration is giving me the rotation shouldn't it give me the movement?

Comment: Its giving you the *acceleration* not the rotation.  It's telling you how much gravity is pulling on each of the 3 axes.

Comment: What do you mean with movement? The accelerometer is measuring the acceleration of the phone.

Comment: I tried using Input.acceleration, nothing happened when I moved the phone but when I tilted it, the object started to move so I do believe it gives me the rotation.

Comment: @XaverKapeller what I mean with movement is taking up the phone and shaking it or bringing it closer or further away from you.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean. Define movement in scientific terms. You don't seem to understand how accelerometers work, read [**this Wikipedia article**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer)

Comment: I mean movement as in when a car is driving it is moving forward, I really don't know how to be more clear about what movement is. All I want to know is if there is a way to see how much the phone is moving and I never said anything about an accelerometer, just any way to measure the movement of the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerometer reads the sum of: **changes** in movement (acceleration) + constant force of gravity. You can use it for directional movement in two ways:

1. Detect changes of gravity angle - when the device is not moving (or is moving at a constant speed) and is parallel to the ground, the accelerometer will read Earth's gravity, ie: `new Vector3(0,-9.81,0)`. When the device is tilted (so not parallel to the ground), the vector's length will still be 9.81, but it will be rotated a bit like. `new Vector3(3.03, -9.32, 0)` (this example is rotation in one axis by 56 degrees (pi/10)). Using this will yield this kind of controlls: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EU3ip4k0uE
2. Detect peaks of acceleration. When the device is still or moving with constant speed, the length of acceleration vector will be equal 9.81, when it changes/starts movement, this number will change. You can detect these changes and interpret this as one time momentary movement (like pressing an arrow).

---

There are alternatives not using an accelometer, for example you can detect some printed marker with Vuforia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RnlBEU5tkI - interpret the relative position to the marker as and action in a simmilar fashion as you'd detect acceleration change in #1.